# update headers authLink react-apollo after authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api, react-apollo

I am using the Github Graphql API.

When my app first loads I send the user off to retrieve an `access_token`. This is working, however, the app has already loaded so I need to update the authorization headers once an access_token has been returned from the server. My code in my `index.js` file looks like the following

```
// request to get access_token
request.post({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/authorize',
  body: JSON.stringify({ code: '123456789' })
}, function(error, response, body){ 
   // token is retrieved at this point, 
   // but the code to set up the Apollo-client 
   // has already been executed.
  let token = body.token
});

// all the code below is executed before the access_token above is returned
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
})

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUBTOKEN}`,
    }
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ApolloProvider client={ client }>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Comment: for anyone else who stumbles across this issue I believe I solved the problem eventually and the approach can be seen in this repo - https://github.com/Pau1fitz/react-github

Comment: Hey Paul, did you find an answer to your question? Looking for the same answer.

Comment: @Ivan apparently I did and it's in the repo above. I am not even sure what question I have asked here  but hopefully this file can help you https://github.com/Pau1fitz/github-graphql-react/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks Paul, it helped a lot. Your App component is stateful, which makes it re-render and so reload the token from localStorage. It works, but it might make my app significally slow. My App is stateless, so there is nothing (yet) what can trigger the reload of the client when token in localStorage has changed.

Comment: I faced this issue and solved it by removing `ApolloProvider` as wrapper of `App` and using it within this `App` component. 
My problem happened because I was calling `Login` component inside `App` to populate `client` but it gets referenced before, that's why always on first time I got an error.

Answer (score -1):

Store the token somewhere on the client. `localStorage` would be a good option.

When you receive the token

```
...
let token = body.token
localStorage.setItem('token')
```

The function you pass to `setContext` gets executed on every request so you can read the token from `localStorage` even after the initial app load.

```
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this, doesn't quite work unfortunately. There is still an issue when the app first loads